# timely in-app purchases on ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, in-app-purchase

Are we able to open any timely in-app (as consumable) for any time period like 1 day or even 1 hour? What is apple's reaction to such in-app?

If I am able to do it, and I don't want it to be a subscription type of in-app (not recurring) what is my in-app's type? Should it be consumable or subscription?

Any articles and tips on timely in-app purchases on iOS, consisting Apple's behaviour would be appriciated.

possible examples:

- 1 Hour Super Strength
- 1 Day Invisibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a typical use of a consumable item. You might want to start the applicable time frame on first use instead of when bought.

Keep in mind that you will need to track the purchase and usage yourself, and it might involve your own server if it's tied to an application that the user can play on several devices or platforms.

Comment: Purchase and usage of it is going to be involve server tracking indeed. But I am not sure how apple will react to such in-app... Is apple cool with 1 hour in-apps?

Comment: I *think* it should be fine, if it's clear to the user what they get. And there are lots of time-based "premium membership" out there, which are not subscription based. They are mostly for longer time periods, but I don't see a conceptional difference. And it's not much different to offering virtual coins that buy exactly that feature for a number of uses.

Comment: exactly... That was what I was thinking... Since "virtual coin" approach can do the same thing, why not directly let the user consider what he/she wants? Probably it is more consumer-friendly approach. Thanks!